# jQuery fadeIn fadeOut Text looks bad in Internet Explorer IE: getting the fix to work

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have tried the solutions previously posted here (and elsewhere) for text looking pixelated and bad during the jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut in Internet Explorer IE.

Two solutions seem common: add a background color or remove the 'filter' attribute.

With this design I cannot use the background color fix (which helps but does not totally remove the issue anyway).

So I have been trying the "remove the filter attribute after the fadeIn" fix.
But it does not fix the text and the "removeAttribute" version the stops the script.
How are you guys getting it to work?

My jQ code is below.

thanks for considering the question!

====================================

// this loop is based on another Stackoverflow answer by Pointy

```
    var divs = $('.myDiv'), i = 0;
    function reveal() {
        if (i == divs.length) divs.fadeIn(inTime, function(){           
            $('.mainPadding').css("height", "4000px"); 
            }); 
        divs.eq(i).fadeIn(inTime, function(){
               //$(this).style.removeAttribute('filter');
               $(this).removeAttr("filter");
            }).delay(waitTime).fadeOut(outTime, function() {
                i++; 
                setTimeout(reveal, 0);
          });
    }
    setTimeout(reveal, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I found on that...


 `// When fading a html node with the .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() 
 // functions in jQuery, IE drops the windows Cleartype rendering; 
 // which results in very ugly text. This override corrects that problem`

```
    jQuery.fn.fadeTo = function(speed, to, callback) {
        return this.animate({ opacity: to }, speed, function() {
            if (to == 1 && jQuery.browser.msie)
                this.style.removeAttribute('filter');

            if (jQuery.isFunction(callback))
                callback();
        });
    };
```

Comment: Thank you John K.  Found something similar at http://jquery.malsup.com/fadetest.html  but it's not fixing things in IE either, still noodling this.  jQuery.fn.fadeIn = function(speed, callback) {     
  return this.animate({opacity: 'show'}, speed, function() {      
  if (jQuery.browser.msie)        
  this.style.removeAttribute('filter');       
  if (jQuery.isFunction(callback))       
  callback();      
  });    
  };        
 [... repeat for fadeOut]

Comment: Well, I have tried putting these overrides in the html page and at the end of the jQuery file itself. but so far it is making no difference in IE.  Is there a special spot this code must be placed in order for it to work?  Thanks again for helping out here, appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure...looks like if you put it in the html page itself, that would work... Have you tried debugging it in IE using the Developer Tools or in Firefox?